# Mobile Safari jQuery Template issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, mobile, safari

Sample code in question

```
<script id="myID" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
   <img src="${imgPath} />
</script>
```

Occasionally and only on mobile safari (regardless of version) this appears broken. It throws the follwing errors

```
Error 404 Not found domain.com/${imgPath}
```

or

```
Error 404 Not Found domain.com/$%7BimgPath%7D
```

So any advice is welcomed

Comment: You have a Typo in your code - wrote <sctipt> insted of <script>

Comment: Fixed, thanks. But this does not solve the issue still.